# In-app billing returns empty signature

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm testing my in-app billing feature, but for some reason, I can't understand why I'm always getting an empty signature (`inapp_signature` field at bundle's extra) when `com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED` is called.

According to the second row of [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) table I would be able to get a signed static response signature. Why does its not happening?

I've already set a test account in my developer account (I didn't published the app) and tried to obtain that signature with no success!

Does anyone have passed through this? Any help would be great. Thaks.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Rooster242, I think so. How to resolve your issue? Answer is: wait! That's it. I have published the app and nothing was working, then, on the next day everything was working like magic (serious, I was tired to understand what was the cause of the problem and then I realize that there wasn't any problem). I think Google's servers are updating data with a huge delay... just wait a few minutes, hours and make sure your installed/ uploaded apks are the same and everything will work fine.

Comment: @yugidroid Did you get signature for static response, when purchasing using developer account?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra no you dont get signature for static response ie android.test.purchased etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have a published version of your APK that contains billing, then you will need to use a developer device. Ie one with same account as your developer console.

You also need to have the same version of the APK installed on your device as the one deployed to Google Play. In fact from memory, the latest APK deployed (not necessarily published) to Google Play needs to the one installed on your device.

And you nee to wait about an hour (it'll vary) from when you deploy to Google Play to when you are guaranteed that the GP instance of your phone can see the version deployed to GP.

Comment: Not getting signature when using a developer's phone also. I factory reseted my phone and configured with my developer's id. Still there is no signature.

Comment: @Krishna I've added a couple of other details that spring to mind and might help you resolve it.